# Interprocess communication with multiprocessing

Tags: multithreading, pyqt, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pyside

I support an application in which the user selects one or more files to be loaded.  The data in each is then transformed during the load process.  I would like to make this concurrent.  Profiling shows that the transformations are the bottleneck.  The transformations are CPU bound (e.g. numpy array manipulations), so I'm using multiprocessing to maximize clock cycles.  I would like to communicate with the processes, or at least receive messages from them, so that I can update the GUI.

To this end, I have the following toy example.  I create a "Relay" thread which manages "Liaisons", each of which listens for messages from a related process.  When messages are received, they're forwarded to the main thread by a signal.  Each process works for a random number of seconds, limited by the spinbox value (default is at most 5 seconds).  Workers send a message for every second they work.

```py
import os
import sys
import time
import random
import multiprocessing as mp
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class RelayMessages:
    stop = 'stop'


class Liaison(QtCore.QObject):

    message = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    kill = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, id, pipe):
        super().__init__()
        self.id = id
        self.pipe = pipe

    def run(self, item):
        self.pipe.send(item)
        self.listen()

    def listen(self):
        self.message.emit(f'Liaison {self.id} listening')
        while True:
            try:
                msg = self.pipe.recv()
                if msg == RelayMessages.stop:
                    self.message.emit(f'Liaison {self.id} stopping listening')
                    self.kill.emit(self.id)
                    break
                self.message.emit(str(msg))
            except EOFError:  # nothing left to receive
                pass


class Relay(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self, connections):
        super().__init__()

        self.liaisons = []

        for id, pipe in enumerate(connections):
            liaison = Liaison(id, pipe)
            self.liaisons.append(liaison)

    def run(self):
        for liaison in self.liaisons:
            liaison.listen()

    def start_workers(self, item):
        for liaison in self.liaisons:
            liaison.pipe.send(item)


class Worker(mp.Process):

    def __init__(self, id, pipe, daemon=True):
        super().__init__()
        self.daemon = daemon
        self.pipe = pipe
        self.id = id

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                item = self.pipe.recv()
                if item:
                    work_load = random.randrange(item)
                    self.pipe.send(f"worker ({self.id}): task will take {work_load} seconds")
                    for i in range(work_load):
                        time.sleep(1)
                        self.pipe.send(f"worker ({self.id}): {i}")
                    self.pipe.send(f"worker ({self.id}): task complete")
                    self.pipe.send(RelayMessages.stop)
                    break
            except EOFError:  # nothing left to receive
                pass


class MyDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    start_workers = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('MP Concurrency')

        self.num_procs = int(mp.cpu_count() / 2)  # 4
        self.relay = None
        self.worker_pool = {}

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'Start {self.num_procs} processes')
        self.button.pressed.connect(self.to_process)

        self.browser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser()

        spin_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.spin = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        self.spin.setValue(5)
        spin_layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('Max work time:'))
        spin_layout.addWidget(self.spin)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(spin_layout)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.browser)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def to_process(self):
        master_connections = []
        slave_connections = []

        print('ID | M_CONN | S_CONN', flush=True)
        for id in range(self.num_procs):
            m_conn, s_conn = mp.Pipe()
            print(id, m_conn.fileno(), s_conn.fileno(), flush=True)
            master_connections.append(m_conn)
            slave_connections.append(s_conn)

        self.relay = Relay(master_connections)
        self.start_workers.connect(self.relay.start_workers)

        for liaison in self.relay.liaisons:
            liaison.message.connect(self.update_ui)
            liaison.kill.connect(self.remove_worker)

        for id, pipe in enumerate(slave_connections):
            worker = Worker(id, pipe)
            self.worker_pool[id] = worker

        self.relay.start()

        self.browser.clear()
        load = self.spin.value()
        for i in range(self.num_procs):
            self.worker_pool[i].start()
            print(f'Started worker ({self.worker_pool[i].pid})', flush=True)

        self.start_workers.emit(load)

    def update_ui(self, text):
        self.browser.append(text)

    def remove_worker(self, id):
        popped = self.worker_pool.pop(id)
        print(f'Removed worker: {id}', flush=True)
        if not self.worker_pool:
            self.browser.append('Processes complete')

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        for i, worker in enumerate(self.worker_pool):
            print(f'Terminating worker {i}', flush=True)
            worker.terminate()
        if self.relay:
            print('Quitting relay thread', flush=True)
            self.relay.quit()
        event.accept()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = MyDialog()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The problem is, messages are displayed in sequence by workers (worker 1, worker 2, etc.) and only when the previous worker has completed.  For example, if the first worker's task takes 2 seconds and the second worker's task is 4 seconds, the messages of the first worker are printed before those of the second worker.  When the second worker's messages are printed, those which were backlogged while the first worker completed are immediately displayed.

Is there a way to make my implementation display messages as they come in?  Is there (for goodness's sake) a better way to implement multiprocessing in PyQt/PySide?  I've opted for Pipes because, although Pool.apply_async is a bit cleaner, I couldn't find a way to have the Pool process communicate back to the main process.  Maybe I should use a QThreadPool and have a separate thread associated with each process?

Comment: I'm not an expert on multiprocessing, so I might be asking the wrong question here but, AFAIK, multithreading already allows using multiple cores in order to maximize CPU processing, and multithreading also allows simpler and more direct inter-process communications. Is there a specific reason for using multiprocessing instead?

Comment: Great question.  I understand threads are suited for I/O bound tasks whereas multiprocessing allows for more clock cycles.  Raymond Hettinger says, "The limit on threads is total CPU power minus the cost of task switches and synchronization overhead."  Granted, that cost is probably low here.  However, I understand QThreads to be a wrapper around Python threads which are limited by the GIL.  (RH says in the same talk that only game devs should worry about GIL.)  Honestly, I didn't think it would be so bad!  So, naivety.  https://pybay.com/site_media/slides/raymond2017-keynote/intro.html

Comment: I believe that good consideration should be taken in balancing if you're getting more benefits from the pro/cons of threadings or those of mp. As said, I've almost no experience on the latter, since most of my needs are usually about 1+ thread(s) doing some "hard work" while ensuring that the UI keeps responsive: performance is not such a big deal. Due the above lack of knowledge on my part, I cannot tell you if your issue is just an implementation bug or not. Certainly, the GIL is a bottleneck for performance; OTOH, mp makes things much more complex (and harder to debug).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like using a separate thread for each process produces the expected result.

**Original Multiprocess Answer**

```py
import os
import sys
import time
import random
import multiprocessing as mp
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


def trap_exc_during_debug(*args):
    # when app raises uncaught exception, print info
    print(args, flush=True)


# install exception hook: without this, uncaught exception would cause application to exit
sys.excepthook = trap_exc_during_debug


class CommandMessages:
    start = 'start'
    stop = 'stop'


class ProcessWorker(mp.Process):

    def __init__(self, id, pipe, work_load, daemon=True):
        super().__init__()
        self.daemon = daemon
        self.pipe = pipe
        self.id = id
        self.work_load = work_load
        print(f'Created worker {self.id} with work_load {self.work_load}', flush=True)

    def run(self):
        self.pipe.send(f"Worker {self.id} in ({os.getpid()})")
        while True:
            try:
                item = self.pipe.recv()
                if item == CommandMessages.start:
                    self.pipe.send(f"worker ({self.id}): task will take {self.work_load} seconds")
                    for i in range(self.work_load):
                        time.sleep(1)
                        self.pipe.send(f"worker ({self.id}): {i}")
                    self.pipe.send(f"worker ({self.id}): task complete")
                    self.pipe.send(CommandMessages.stop)
                    break
            except EOFError:  # nothing left to receive
                pass


class ThreadWorkerSignals(QtCore.QObject):
    done = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int) # worker id
    message = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)


class ThreadWorker(QtCore.QRunnable):

    def __init__(self, id, max_load):
        super().__init__()

        self.signals = ThreadWorkerSignals()

        self.id = id
        self.max_load = max_load
        self._abort = False

    def run(self):
        thread_name = QtCore.QThread.currentThread().objectName()
        thread_id = int(QtCore.QThread.currentThreadId())  # cast to int() to get Id, otherwise it's sip object
        self.signals.message.emit(f'Running ThreadWorker {self.id} from thread "{thread_name}" (#{thread_id})')

        work_load = random.randrange(self.max_load)
        self.signals.message.emit(f'ThreadWorker #{self.id} work_load is {work_load}')

        m_conn, s_conn = mp.Pipe()
        self.pipe = m_conn
        self.process_worker = ProcessWorker(self.id, s_conn, work_load)

        self.signals.message.emit(f'ThreadWorker {self.id}: starting self.process_worker...')
        self.process_worker.start()

        self.pipe.send(CommandMessages.start)
        self.listen()

    def listen(self):
        self.signals.message.emit(f'ThreadWorker {self.id} listening')
        while True:
            try:
                msg = self.pipe.recv()
                if msg == CommandMessages.stop:
                    self.signals.message.emit(f'ThreadWorker {self.id}: closing process_worker...')
                    self.process_worker.join(2)
                    self.process_worker.terminate()
                    print(f'ThreadWorker {self.id}: process_worker closed', flush=True)
                    self.signals.message.emit(f'ThreadWorker {self.id}: process_worker closed')
                    self.signals.done.emit(self.id)
                    break
                self.signals.message.emit(str(msg))
            except EOFError:  # nothing left to receive
                pass

    def abort(self):
        self.signals.message.emit(f'ThreadWorker #{self.id} notified to abort')
        self._abort = True


class MyDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    abort = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.start_time = None

        self.setWindowTitle('MP Concurrency with QThreadPool')
        self.resize(600, 400)

        self.num_procs = int(mp.cpu_count() / 2)  # 4

        self._thread_pool = QtCore.QThreadPool.globalInstance()
        QtCore.QThread.currentThread().setObjectName('main')

        self.threads = []

        self.start_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'Start {self.num_procs} processes')
        self.start_button.pressed.connect(self.start_processes)

        self.abort_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'Abort')
        self.abort_button.pressed.connect(self.on_abort)
        self.abort_button.setEnabled(False)

        self.log = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser()

        spin_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.spin = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        self.spin.setValue(5)
        spin_layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('Max work time:'))
        spin_layout.addWidget(self.spin)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(spin_layout)
        layout.addWidget(self.start_button)
        layout.addWidget(self.abort_button)
        layout.addWidget(self.log)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def start_processes(self):
        self.log.clear()

        self.thread_count = self.num_procs
        self.threads = []
        self._threads_completed = 0

        max_load = self.spin.value()
        self.start_time = time.time()
        for idx in range(self.thread_count):
            thread_worker = ThreadWorker(idx, max_load)
            self.threads.append(thread_worker)

            thread_worker.signals.done.connect(self.on_done)
            thread_worker.signals.message.connect(self.on_message)

            self.abort.connect(thread_worker.abort)

            self._thread_pool.start(thread_worker)

            self.start_button.setEnabled(False)
            self.abort_button.setEnabled(True)

    def on_message(self, text):
        self.log.append(str(text))

    def on_done(self, id):
        self.log.append(f'ThreadWorker {id} is done')
        self._threads_completed += 1

        if self._threads_completed == self.thread_count:
            self.log.append('No more workers active')
            self.log.append(f'Elapsed time: {time.time() - self.start_time}')
            self.start_button.setEnabled(True)
            self.abort_button.setEnabled(False)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_abort(self):
        self.abort.emit()
        self.log.append('Asking each thread worker to abort')
        done = self._thread_pool.waitForDone(10000)
        if not done:
            self.log.append('WARNING: COULD NOT CLOSE THREADS')
        else:
            self.log.append('All threads exited')

        self.log.append(f'Elapsed time: {time.time() - self.start_time}')

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.abort.emit()
        done = self._thread_pool.waitForDone(5000)
        if not done:
            print('Threads still open!. Open that task manager!', flush=True)
        else:
            print('All threads exited', flush=True)

        event.accept()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = MyDialog()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Multiprocess vs Threading**

I happened to have a "pure" threading example laying around which was close enough that I figured I could compare the two approaches.  The threads and processes are set to the max, which may or may not be ideal.  There's a global containing a set of large numbers.  Those numbers are passed to each process or thread and used to do menial work.  I was surprised to see that the multiprocessing approach wins:

```
Multiprocess time: 34.82416486740112
Threaded time: 57.59582781791687
```

This was fun, in an odd sort of way.  Maybe someone else will find it useful or improve upon it.  (The abort/cleanup process was not thoroughly put together).

```py
import os
import sys
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


WORK_LOAD = [123456779, 98765554, 7666111, 966325, 978798, 65465, 447733331, 94613697]


def trap_exc_during_debug(*args):
    # when app raises uncaught exception, print info
    print(args, flush=True)


# install exception hook: without this, uncaught exception would cause application to exit
sys.excepthook = trap_exc_during_debug


class CommandMessages:
    start = 'start'
    stop = 'stop'


class ProcessWorker(mp.Process):

    def __init__(self, id, pipe, work_load, daemon=True):
        super().__init__()
        self.daemon = daemon
        self.pipe = pipe
        self.id = id
        self.work_load = work_load
        print(f'Created worker {self.id} with work_load {self.work_load}', flush=True)

    def run(self):
        self.pipe.send(f"PureThreadWorker {self.id} in ({os.getpid()})")
        while True:
            try:
                item = self.pipe.recv()
                if item == CommandMessages.start:
                    self.pipe.send(f"worker ({self.id}): starting task")
                    lst = []
                    for i in range(self.work_load):
                        lst.append('x')
                    self.pipe.send(f"worker ({self.id}): task complete")
                    self.pipe.send(CommandMessages.stop)
                    break
            except EOFError:  # nothing left to receive
                pass


class ThreadWorkerSignals(QtCore.QObject):
    done = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int) # worker id
    message = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)


class ProcessThreadWorker(QtCore.QRunnable):

    def __init__(self, id, work_load):
        super().__init__()

        self.signals = ThreadWorkerSignals()

        self.id = id
        self.work_load = work_load
        self._abort = False

    def run(self):
        thread_name = QtCore.QThread.currentThread().objectName()
        thread_id = int(QtCore.QThread.currentThreadId())  # cast to int() to get Id, otherwise it's sip object
        self.signals.message.emit(f'Running ProcessThreadWorker {self.id} from thread "{thread_name}" (#{thread_id})')

        self.signals.message.emit(f'ProcessThreadWorker #{self.id} work_load is {self.work_load}')

        m_conn, s_conn = mp.Pipe()
        self.pipe = m_conn
        self.process_worker = ProcessWorker(self.id, s_conn, self.work_load)

        self.signals.message.emit(f'ProcessThreadWorker {self.id}: starting self.process_worker...')
        self.process_worker.start()

        self.pipe.send(CommandMessages.start)
        self.listen()

    def listen(self):
        self.signals.message.emit(f'ProcessThreadWorker {self.id} listening')
        while True:
            try:
                msg = self.pipe.recv()
                if msg == CommandMessages.stop:
                    self.signals.message.emit(f'ProcessThreadWorker {self.id}: closing process_worker...')
                    self.process_worker.join(2)
                    self.process_worker.terminate()
                    print(f'ProcessThreadWorker {self.id}: process_worker closed', flush=True)
                    self.signals.message.emit(f'ProcessThreadWorker {self.id}: process_worker closed')
                    self.signals.done.emit(self.id)
                    break
                self.signals.message.emit(str(msg))
            except EOFError:  # nothing left to receive
                pass

    def abort(self):
        self.signals.message.emit(f'ProcessThreadWorker #{self.id} notified to abort')
        self._abort = True


class PureThreadWorker(QtCore.QRunnable):

    def __init__(self, id, work_load):
        super().__init__()

        self.signals = ThreadWorkerSignals()

        self.id = id
        self.work_load = work_load
        self._abort = False

    def run(self):
        thread_name = QtCore.QThread.currentThread().objectName()
        thread_id = int(QtCore.QThread.currentThreadId())  # cast to int() to get Id, otherwise it's sip object
        self.signals.message.emit(f'Running ProcessThreadWorker {self.id} from thread "{thread_name}" (#{thread_id})')
        self.signals.message.emit(f'PureThreadWorker {self.id} work_load is {self.work_load}')

        self.signals.message.emit(f"PureThreadWorker {self.id}: starting task")
        lst = []
        for i in range(self.work_load):
            lst.append('x')
        self.signals.message.emit(f"PureThreadWorker {self.id}: task complete")

        self.signals.done.emit(self.id)

    def abort(self):
        self.signals.message.emit(f'PureThreadWorker #{self.id} notified to abort')
        self._abort = True


class MyDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    abort = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.start_time = None

        self.setWindowTitle('MP Concurrency with QThreadPool')
        self.resize(600, 400)

        self.num_procs = mp.cpu_count()

        self._thread_pool = QtCore.QThreadPool.globalInstance()
        QtCore.QThread.currentThread().setObjectName('main')

        self.threads = []

        self.button_start_processes = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'Start {self.num_procs} processes')
        self.button_start_processes.pressed.connect(self.start_processes)

        self.button_start_threads = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.button_start_threads.clicked.connect(self.start_threads)
        self.button_start_threads.setText(f"Start {self._thread_pool.maxThreadCount()} threads")

        self.abort_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(f'Abort')
        self.abort_button.pressed.connect(self.on_abort)
        self.abort_button.setEnabled(False)

        self.log = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser()

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button_start_processes)
        layout.addWidget(self.button_start_threads)
        layout.addWidget(self.abort_button)
        layout.addWidget(self.log)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def start_processes(self):
        self.log.clear()

        self.thread_count = self.num_procs
        self.threads = []
        self._threads_completed = 0
        self.log.append(f'Max procs: {self.num_procs}')

        self.start_time = time.time()
        for idx in range(self.thread_count):
            thread_worker = ProcessThreadWorker(idx, WORK_LOAD[idx])
            self.threads.append(thread_worker)

            thread_worker.signals.done.connect(self.on_process_done)
            thread_worker.signals.message.connect(self.on_message)

            self.abort.connect(thread_worker.abort)

            self._thread_pool.start(thread_worker)

            self.button_start_processes.setEnabled(False)
            self.abort_button.setEnabled(True)

    def start_threads(self):
        self.log.clear()

        self.pure_workers_done = 0
        self.pure_workers = []
        self.worker_count = self._thread_pool.maxThreadCount()
        self.log.append(f'Max threads: {self._thread_pool.maxThreadCount()}')

        self.start_time = time.time()
        for idx in range(self.worker_count):
            worker = PureThreadWorker(idx, WORK_LOAD[idx])
            self.pure_workers.append(worker)

            # get progress messages from worker:
            worker.signals.done.connect(self.on_pure_done)
            worker.signals.message.connect(self.log.append)

            # control worker:
            self.abort.connect(worker.abort)

            self._thread_pool.start(worker)

            self.button_start_processes.setEnabled(False)
            self.abort_button.setEnabled(True)

    def on_message(self, text):
        self.log.append(str(text))

    def on_process_done(self, id):
        self.log.append(f'ProcessThreadWorker {id} is done')
        self._threads_completed += 1

        if self._threads_completed == self.thread_count:
            self.log.append('No more workers active')
            self.log.append(f'Elapsed time: {time.time() - self.start_time}')
            print(f'Elapsed time: {time.time() - self.start_time}', flush=True)
            self.button_start_processes.setEnabled(True)
            self.abort_button.setEnabled(False)

    def on_pure_done(self, id):
        self.log.append(f'PureThreadWorker {id} is done')
        self.pure_workers_done += 1

        if self.pure_workers_done == self.worker_count:
            self.log.append('No more pure workers active')
            self.log.append(f'Elapsed time: {time.time() - self.start_time}')
            print(f'Elapsed time: {time.time() - self.start_time}', flush=True)
            self.button_start_processes.setEnabled(True)
            self.abort_button.setEnabled(False)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_abort(self):
        self.abort.emit()
        self.log.append('Asking each thread worker to abort')
        done = self._thread_pool.waitForDone(10000)
        if not done:
            self.log.append('WARNING: COULD NOT CLOSE THREADS')
        else:
            self.log.append('All threads exited')

        self.log.append(f'Elapsed time: {time.time() - self.start_time}')
        print(f'Elapsed time: {time.time() - self.start_time}', flush=True)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.abort.emit()
        done = self._thread_pool.waitForDone(5000)
        if not done:
            print('Threads still open!. Open that task manager!', flush=True)
        else:
            print('All threads exited', flush=True)

        event.accept()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = MyDialog()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: the benefit of using threads rather than processes is that you can directly emit the signals you want from the thread doing your processing. You may also see performance benefit as well because many numpy functions release the GIL. The complexity will be what it is... You can simplify if you make more assumptions, and a less flexible system, but that may accumulate as technical debt which will bite you later on.

Comment: For sure.  Thank you for sharing your thoughts.  At this point, I figured since I'm here, I may as well finish what I start and see this little experiment through.

Comment: from *The Zen of Python - Tim Peters*: "Complex is better than complicated" "If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea"